# Player collision with 2D array tilemap

Tags: c#, arrays, xna, collision

I've currently got my tile map drawn with a 2D array and my character moving and drawn also.

I'm now trying to sort out the collision side of this, I'm looking to reference the player position to the tile map coords and if they are equal perform the necessary actions for the collision.

However I have tried to compare the player position vector to the 2D array and I keep getting errors such as `"Cannot implicitly convert int to bool"`

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this condition that I need to check.
The code which yields the compilation error is `if(player.Position == Tiles.Map[(int)player.Position.X, (int)playerPosition.Y])`

Here is how I've drawn my map:

```
public int[,] Map = new int[,]
{
    {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
};

public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    int tileMapWidth = Map.GetLength(1);
    int tileMapHeight = Map.GetLength(0);

    for (int x = 0; x < tileMapWidth; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < tileMapHeight; y++)
        {
            int textureIndex = Map[y, x];
            Texture2D texture = tileTextures[textureIndex];

            spriteBatch.Draw(
                texture,
                source = new Rectangle(x * myTile.Width,
                    y * myTile.Height,
                    tileWidth,
                    tileHeight),
                Color.White);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I was wondering if anyone could help me with this condition that I need to check.` Well, without seeing the code where you check the collision nobody can help you. If your problem is in a concrete function don't post an unrelated one, if you go to the doctor with a pain on a leg you don't show him a hand, you show the leg, true?

Comment: I explained above that I want to check the player position with the 2d array[x,y]. But my issue was "Cannot implicitly convert int to bool". Without the condition working or being met the collision code is redundant.

The condition I attempted was:

if(player.Position == Tiles.Map[(int)player.Position.X, (int)playerPosition.Y])

This is where my issue is, I'm unsure how to go about writing this condition correctly.

Comment: No, is not redundant as we can't see why you're getting that exception.

Comment: The minimum would be at least add the code which doesn't compiles

Comment: The error is "Cannot implicitly convert int to bool"

if(player.Position == Tiles.Map[(int)player.Position.X, (int)playerPosition.Y])

Comment: Yes, very nice exception, but which code yields it?

Comment: Ok, add that to the question, the answer is simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to compare the player position with an array of integers, but what you want is to check if the array has a "1" as value on the player's position.

Change

```
if(player.Position == Tiles.Map[(int)player.Position.X, (int)playerPosition.Y])
```

To

```
 if(Tiles.Map[(int)player.Position.X, (int)playerPosition.Y] == 1)
```

Else, if you konw a concrete position of the map (lets call them X and Y) then the array isn't involved at all, it should be like this:

```
if((int)player.Position.X == X && (int)playerPosition.Y == Y)
```

Comment: Thank you very much appreciated.

Comment: that's because the player position is outside the map array, does the map array map 1:1 to the player's position? or maybe each X units of the player's position represent a cell? Also, this is another error, add a new question and please, this time add the correct code.

Comment: Yeah i forgot to divide the position by the size of the tiles X and Y.

Thanks again I've marked as solved :)